# Why am I getting "This field may not be null" errors when populating decimal and char fields from serialized data via Serializer in Django Model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to populate `DecimalField` and `CharField` fields in a Django Model from serialized data via DRF Serializer, but I am getting strange errors of `This field may not be null`. Here is my model definition:

```
class Product(BaseModel):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    recommended_action = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    recommended_action_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=8)
    recommended_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=8)
    rrp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=8)
    iam_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=8)
    iam_index = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=8)
    factor = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=8)
    avg_in_stock = models.DecimalField(
        null=True, blank=True, max_digits=12, decimal_places=8
    )
```

Here is my model serializer definition:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Product
        fields = "__all__"
```

And here is my view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def migrate_data(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        product_serialized_data = serializers.ProductSerializer(
            data=data,
            many=True,
            context={"request": request},
        )
        if not product_serialized_data.is_valid():
            print(product_serialized_data.errors)
    product_serialized_data.save()
    return Response(data={"detail": "Success"})
```

This is the data that I am passing to the POST request:

```
{
    "product": "DE_Ford_2095160",
    "recommended_action": "increase",
    "recommended_action_value": 0.0315553,
    "recommended_price": 14.5862,
    "rrp": 14.14,
    "iam_price": 6.56898,
    "iam_index": 0.464567,
    "factor": 2.15254,
    "avg_in_stock": 1
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following errors:

```
[
    {
        'recommended_action': [ErrorDetail(string='This field may not be null.', code='null')],
        'recommended_action_value': [ErrorDetail(string='This field may not be null.', code='null')],
        'recommended_price': [ErrorDetail(string='This field may not be null.', code='null')],
        'rrp': [ErrorDetail(string='This field may not be null.', code='null')],
        'iam_index': [ErrorDetail(string='This field may not be null.', code='null')],
        'factor': [ErrorDetail(string='This field may not be null.', code='null')]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reason, but I just added `null = True` and `blank = True` in my Model, for those fields declaration which were showing error `This may not be null`. So the updated Model code which worked for me is below:

```
class Product(BaseModel):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    recommended_action = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=Ture)
    recommended_action_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=8, null=True, blank=Ture)
    recommended_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=8, null=True, blank=Ture)
    rrp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=8, null=True, blank=Ture)
    iam_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=8, null=True, blank=Ture)
    iam_index = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=8, null=True, blank=Ture)
    factor = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=8, null=True, blank=Ture)
    avg_in_stock = models.DecimalField(
        null=True, blank=True, max_digits=12, decimal_places=8
    )
```

I don't know the reason, but it worked for me. If anyone knows the reason, please explain so that me and other viewers of this question understand the cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

because you're using serializers and APIs you must get the data from `request.data` not `request.body`, so your accessing the wrong data which is don't have the `recommended_action` field which case the error.

Comment: I did what you suggested. The difference in your approach is to get the direct dictionary data, but my approach was to deserialize JSON byte object and then get dictionary data. So, in the end I am still getting `This field may not be null`. Can you look what's wrong? Because the field `product` has no issue, it just show this error on other fields.

Comment: BTW, I guess you were not able to see full error, that's why I reformatted it in my question, and you can see the full error now without scrolling horizontally. Please can you have a look at my question again?

Comment: how do you send the data I noticed that the only fields that raise an error are the `double` so I guess that the problem coming from how you send the data.

Comment: There's another field that is showing error and is not `double` and that is `recommended_action` field. BTW, I am getting data from a JSON file via `json` library and using `requests` library to make a POST request to the API, basically this is the line of code which is sending the POST request `requests.post(local_backend_url, json=json.load(database_file_handle))`

Comment: I added my own answer to the question, if you know the reason that why it worked from me which I explained in my answer, please write the reason as a comment under my answer. Thanks